# Direct Show SetNotifyWindow function

Tags: c#, winapi, directshow, directshow.net

From [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/) I have downloaded some samples to help me in using Direct Show library.In the code he defined a constant(use it as address) to use it in **SetNotifyWindow** I don't understand why we refer to certain Message defined finally by us.

Constant (Message):

```
 // Application-defined message to notify app of filtergraph events
 public const int WM_GRAPHNOTIFY = 0x8000 + 1;
```

Media event property:

```
// provides method to retrieve the events 
IMediaEventEx mediaEventEx;
```

`SetNotifyWindow` function use this address:

```
 //set the notify window
        //(NB:hr-->hresult (com device error for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
        int hr = mediaEventEx.SetNotifyWindow(ptr, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Have a read on the `Windows Message Loop`.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Even more reason to google it :) But anyway, let's say you want to get events from multiple `IMediaEventEx` sources, then the ability to differentiate them by different message numbers might be handy. There's no other reason.

Comment: I wiki it before replying :).what make me confuse is that we define it so if it is an already standard why we put its number self?

Comment: It's actually not a standard. You may use whatever number you please! Just make sure it doesn't collide with normal window messages.

Comment: but @Chris in the sample I see it is used once so if I use it self and I define whatever I want why I is not mentioned anymore.Sorry I feel like I am stupid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting up the notification. You tell FGM what message to send back to you when you are supposed to jump in with some processing.

From [MSDN on `IMediaEventEx::SetNotifyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **When the window receives the message**, it should call the `IMediaEvent::GetEvent` method to retrieve the event. Events are asynchronous, so the queue might contain several events (or none). Call GetEvent repeatedly, until it returns an error code.

Comment: I understand what the function do but I don't understand what do you mean by FGM

Comment: also send back to you where could you give more details

Comment: FGM = Filter Graph Manager, COM object which backs filter graph interfaces: `IFilterGraph`, `IGraphBuilder`, `IMediaControl` etc.